# Dynamically appending Text to a <span> element inside a <p> element breaks my design

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a Dialog box which displays  a message to the user about deleting a file, as follows:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Delete File?                                                          |
|                                                                       |
| Are you sure you want to delete 'nameoffile.txt' from your storage?   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The corresponding html :

```
 <p>Are you sure you want to delete '
 <span class = "delete-filename"></span>
 ' from your Cloud?</p>
```

The file name is being appended to the  tag(delete-filename) through javascript code:

```
$(".delete-filename").text(filter_name(get_name("text"));
```

The Problem:
Whenever the filename is let's say 30chars long, the text within the p tags overlaps the dialog box and results in this :

```
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Delete File?                                                          |
 |                                                                       |
 | Are you sure you want to delete ' longfilename-longfilename.txt' from your storage?   
 +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

My Query: How can I solve this? Is this a design flaw? I noticed that the p tag predetermines its width and height before the span tag is populated, and not after.Is this the problem here? Whats the workaround?Thanks Chris.p

Comment: The workaround is say to wrap the text to the second line?

Comment: How is your dialog box created? Which element do you use to render it?

Comment: @VisioN how do you mean? would you kindly specify which line

Comment: Can you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: @user2678538 That's in CSS of the dialog box making its height flexible, not fixed. Or setting a room for line wrapping.

Comment: @Jonathan with a <div> element

Comment: Have you set a fixed width to the div then? And let the height variable as VisioN suggests?

Comment: Ok, Yes I have set the width and height so that I can display the dialog box in the center! I commented out the width and height and it works! but not centered anymore!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to wrap the holding box with some width.

```
p {
    background: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 420px;
}
span.delete-filename {
    color: red;
}
```

Something like this you are looking? Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AhuTz/